# Lambda operator in .net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

May be silly but stumped by this.

When I created a new empty .net core project using VS 2017, I have this Program.cs file.

The program class in the file looks as follows.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I am not able to get whats happening in the last line, specifically after the lambda operator(=>)? That does not seem to be a lambda expression. What is that?

Could someone explain what the following line is all about. I know lambda expressions, but could not figure out this.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: That's C#7 syntax for "Expression Bodied Methods": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=>` symbol has different meanings in different parts of your C# code. The specific part you're asking about here is called an [Expression Bodied Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

You can use this to declare methods that only have a single statement. If the statement returns a value, and the method is declared to return a value, it will also implicitly return the value from the statement.

Here are examples of expression bodied methods:

#### Getter-only Properties

```
public int Value => 42;
```

#### Getter and setters

```
public int Value
{
    get => _Value;
    set => _Value = value;
}
```

*(note that you can also mix and match this with traditional syntax so you have have an expression bodied getter method and the traditional setter with curly braces)*

*(expression bodied properties are new in C# 7)*

#### Methods

```
public void WriteLog(string message) => Console.WriteLine(message);
public int Sum(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

*(the first method does not return anything, so while the name of the syntax contains "expression", it doesn't **have** to evaluate to something)*

#### Constructors

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly int _Value;
    public Test(int value) => _Value = value;
```

*(expression bodied constructors are new in C# 7)*

#### Destructor (finalizer)

```
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    ~Test() => Dispose(false);
```

*(expression bodied destructors are new in C# 7)*

#### Constructors that set multiple values

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly int _A;
    private readonly int _B;
    public Test(int a, int b) => (_A, _B) = (a, b);
```

*(note that this last example also uses tuples, **use this syntax for constructors responsibly**)*

Answer (score 6):

You can use it instead of curly braces if you are just returning a single expression.

This

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Is the same as this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
   return  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```